# android rounded rectangle without background straight-edge rectangle

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a dialog that appears as a rounded rectangle.  I'm doing this by specifying   the following shape xml as the background for the dialog layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid    android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners  android:radius="40dp"/>
    <padding  android:left="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

The resulting dialog has rounded corners inside a black 90 degree rectangle.  I want to know how I can get rid of the ninety degree rectangle that remains and show nothing but the rounded rectangle.

It seems like the rectangle template stays behind after I curve the corners:

Here's a link to a picture of the dialog my code's producing: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/8292/photoon20110912at2032.jpg

Comment: One of the following may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101623/how-to-add-rounded-corners-to-translucent-background-of-activity or http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html I don't actually have experience with custom dialogs, but those two links looked like they may answer your question.

Comment: Your code works for me, I think your issue is whatever is in the dialog is fill parent and this has sharp corners that are pushing passed your radius rounded corner. Try increasing the padding to 100dip just to test this.

Comment: @Blundell Worked for me - thanks!. The same problem. Rounded corners, but outside the corners some unwanted background, as if there were a rectangle around the shape. I spent ages trying to color that background from within the shape, and nothing worked. I then set the padding in the shape to 100dp, and found that the problem was in the parent. It was clear as soon as I put the extra padding in. In short..the standard solution for rounded buttons, with a shape and corners, works and just places the rounded shape onto the background.

Answer (score 5):

Write your constructor as:

`public CustomDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }`

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i was looking for.
Also you can use it without your own constructor: MyDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#B7B7B7"/>
<corners android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dip"
    android:topRightRadius="8dip"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I don't think this is any different than the code I already have.  I'm not sure what the orientation, width, and height properties do differently in this case, but I didn't notice any change with my dialog.  My rectangle is wrapping around a TextView, so it seems like the size of my dialog is only determined by the text view and the padding.

Comment: well i gave you something which worked for me. well can you give a screenshot of what you are getting now? so that may be ill try in some other way

Answer (score 4):

This will give you the required rounded rectangle without background:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:angle="270"/>
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FFF"/>
<corners
    android:radius="40dp"/>     

</shape>
```

**UPDATE for future reference** (it was added as comments)

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext(); 
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); dialog.show();
```

Comment: I copied it verbatim but all that's different is an outline of the rounded rectangle within the black template rectangle.  I added a picture to show you what I'm getting from the code I posted.  What does the gradient do?  My understanding is it was used for color changes across the dialog.  If this worked for you, then I must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: I apologize for the late response, it took time to figure out the solution. Try this to get rid of the black ninety degree rectangle:
    
    `Context mContext = getApplicationContext();`
    `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);`
    `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);`
    `dialog.show();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: ahh thank you so much i've spend way too long than i should on this

Answer (score 0):

I was shocked when I occured the same problem, the solution is also a little weird. Create  your own custom drawable for eg see below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/text_highlight" />

    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@color/text_highlight" />

    <corners android:radius="12dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

Add the following lines to your dialog:

```
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

 // This is line that does all the magic
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(                             
 R.drawable.dialog_rounded);
```