# Android AlertDialog with rounded corners: rectangle seen below corners

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, custom-view

I want a `Dialog` with rounded corners, but when the `Dialog` is seen there's a rectangle below it that's seen below the corners, like this:

[image]

I build the `dialog` using a custom `DialogFragment`:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.playdialog, null));
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

The dialog layout (playdialog) has the following drawable as background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid
        android:color="#AAAAAAAA" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FF000000" />

    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

As I said, I set this drawable as background:

```
android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
```

I don't want that rectangle to be seen. How can I do it??

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396529/android-rounded-rectangle-without-background-straight-edge-rectangle) post the user had the same problem. I tried to use the solution that worked for him but it didn't work for me. I modified my `DialogFragment` like this:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.playdialog, null));
    Dialog d = builder.create();
    d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    return d;
}
```

The result is exactly the same. How can I remove that rectangle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I was shocked when I occured the same problem, the solution is also a little weird. Create  your own custom drawable for eg see below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@color/text_highlight" />

    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="@color/text_highlight" />

    <corners android:radius="12dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

Add the following lines to your dialog:

```
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

 // This is line that does all the magic
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(                             
 R.drawable.dialog_rounded);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to set the style of your `DialogFragment` to `Theme_Translucent.`

```
setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

i set a transparent background to the dialog in code.
try this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0x00ffffff));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add
`getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

to the `onCreateView()` method of your MyDialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
customDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```